# How to add multiple objects to the scene?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

A set of handles has been created that can be used to resize a shape.
By tracking the changes in the position of the handles, you calculate the new geometry of the shape.

I can not add multiple objects to the scene.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPainterPath, QPainter, QColor, QPen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsRectItem, QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem


class GraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):

    handleTopLeft = 1
    handleTopMiddle = 2
    handleTopRight = 3
    handleMiddleLeft = 4
    handleMiddleRight = 5
    handleBottomLeft = 6
    handleBottomMiddle = 7
    handleBottomRight = 8

    handleSize = +8.0
    handleSpace = -4.0

    handleCursors = {
        handleTopLeft: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
        handleTopMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        handleTopRight: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        handleMiddleLeft: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        handleMiddleRight: Qt.SizeHorCursor,
        handleBottomLeft: Qt.SizeBDiagCursor,
        handleBottomMiddle: Qt.SizeVerCursor,
        handleBottomRight: Qt.SizeFDiagCursor,
    }

    def __init__(self, *args):
        """
        Initialize the shape.
        """
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.handles = {}
        self.handleSelected = None
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
        self.updateHandlesPos()

    def handleAt(self, point):
        """
        Returns the resize handle below the given point.
        """
        for k, v, in self.handles.items():
            if v.contains(point):
                return k
        return None

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, moveEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse moves over the shape (NOT PRESSED).
        """
        if self.isSelected():
            handle = self.handleAt(moveEvent.pos())
            cursor = Qt.ArrowCursor if handle is None else self.handleCursors[handle]
            self.setCursor(cursor)
        super().hoverMoveEvent(moveEvent)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, moveEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse leaves the shape (NOT PRESSED).
        """
        self.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(moveEvent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is pressed on the item.
        """
        self.handleSelected = self.handleAt(mouseEvent.pos())
        if self.handleSelected:
            self.mousePressPos = mouseEvent.pos()
            self.mousePressRect = self.boundingRect()
        super().mousePressEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is being moved over the item while being pressed.
        """
        if self.handleSelected is not None:
            self.interactiveResize(mouseEvent.pos())
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
        """
        Executed when the mouse is released from the item.
        """
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent)
        self.handleSelected = None
        self.mousePressPos = None
        self.mousePressRect = None
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        """
        Returns the bounding rect of the shape (including the resize handles).
        """
        o = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
        return self.rect().adjusted(-o, -o, o, o)

    def updateHandlesPos(self):
        """
        Update current resize handles according to the shape size and position.
        """
        s = self.handleSize
        b = self.boundingRect()
        self.handles[self.handleTopLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleTopMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleTopRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.top(), s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleMiddleLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleMiddleRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.center().y() - s / 2, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomLeft] = QRectF(b.left(), b.bottom() - s, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomMiddle] = QRectF(b.center().x() - s / 2, b.bottom() - s, s, s)
        self.handles[self.handleBottomRight] = QRectF(b.right() - s, b.bottom() - s, s, s)

    def interactiveResize(self, mousePos):
        """
        Perform shape interactive resize.
        """
        offset = self.handleSize + self.handleSpace
        boundingRect = self.boundingRect()
        rect = self.rect()
        diff = QPointF(0, 0)

        self.prepareGeometryChange()

        if self.handleSelected == self.handleTopLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopMiddle:

            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleTopRight:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.top()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            boundingRect.setTop(toY)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            rect.setTop(boundingRect.top() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleMiddleRight:
            print("MR")
            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomLeft:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.left()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setLeft(toX)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setLeft(boundingRect.left() + offset)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomMiddle:

            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        elif self.handleSelected == self.handleBottomRight:

            fromX = self.mousePressRect.right()
            fromY = self.mousePressRect.bottom()
            toX = fromX + mousePos.x() - self.mousePressPos.x()
            toY = fromY + mousePos.y() - self.mousePressPos.y()
            diff.setX(toX - fromX)
            diff.setY(toY - fromY)
            boundingRect.setRight(toX)
            boundingRect.setBottom(toY)
            rect.setRight(boundingRect.right() - offset)
            rect.setBottom(boundingRect.bottom() - offset)
            self.setRect(rect)

        self.updateHandlesPos()

    def shape(self):
        """
        Returns the shape of this item as a QPainterPath in local coordinates.
        """
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRect(self.rect())
        if self.isSelected():
            for shape in self.handles.values():
                path.addEllipse(shape)
        return path

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        """
        Paint the node in the graphic view.
        """
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 100)))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())

        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0, 255)))
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0, 255), 1.0, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        for handle, rect in self.handles.items():
            if self.handleSelected is None or handle == self.handleSelected:
                painter.drawEllipse(rect)


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    grview = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 680, 459)

    scene.addPixmap(QPixmap('01.png'))
    grview.setScene(scene)

    item = GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 300, 150)
    scene.addItem(item)

    grview.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    grview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect that several objects (rectangles) will be located in the scene, and each of them can be freely moved.

Comment: I do not understand you, what is your problem ?, when I execute the code I see a rectangle that has circles as handlers. What do you get?

Comment: I only see that you have added a GraphicsRectItem, why do you think that when you add an element you will see several?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only added a single GraphicsRectItem so you only see one item, if you want to see more then you must create more GraphicsRectItem and add them to the scene with addItem:

```py
# ...

import random

def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    grview = QGraphicsView()
    scene = QGraphicsScene(grview)
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 680, 459)
    grview.setScene(scene)
    for _ in range(10):
        item = GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 300, 150)
        scene.addItem(item)
        item.setPos(QPointF(*random.sample(range(300), 2)))

    grview.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    grview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# ...
```

[image]

**Update:**

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPointF, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QPainterPath, QPainter, QColor, QPen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QGraphicsRectItem,
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
)


class GraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    # ...


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        button = QPushButton("Add Rectangle", clicked=self.on_clicked)
        self.grview = QGraphicsView()
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self.grview)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 680, 459)
        self.grview.setScene(scene)
        self.grview.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.grview)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        item = GraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 300, 150)
        item.setPos(QPointF(*random.sample(range(300), 2)))
        self.grview.scene().addItem(item)


import random


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Sorry,I did not correctly interpret the question. I need a button, when I click on it, a new rectangle is added to the scene.

Comment: how to add a line? so you can do the same manipulations with it (add, move, resize) as with a rectangle